# how to implement Scroll down to hide action bar like playstore app?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

How to implement Scroll down to hide action bar like play store app?
Any reference projects (github or any) or tips?

Here is my base activity code which holds both action bar and fragment.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F44336"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarrel">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            />
        <com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch.SearchBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchbox"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:background="#F44336"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbarrel"
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: @HirenRathod check the edit.

Answer (score -1):

Try using **Coordinator Layout**.

CoordinatorLayout extends the ability to accomplish many of the Google's Material Design scrolling effects. Currently, there are several ways provided in this framework that allow it to work without needing to write your own custom animation code.

More information about [Handling Scrolls with CoordinatorLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/rvToDoList"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/rvToDoList"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```